# Convert jQuery date to php date or mysql date to be inserted correctly in database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I use jQuery datepicker with the following code

```
$(".item").datepicker({
  showWeek: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  minDate: -30,
  dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
});
```

The value of that datepicker will be sent via ajax to php function which insert a data in mysql table.

The `date` column type from mysql database is `Datetime`.

Every time when read value from datepicker input value, the `date` column in database is empty shows `00-00-0000 00:00:00`.

I am newbie in php and maybe I made somewhere a mistake.

the php piece of code

`mysqli_query($connect, "Insert into tab(date) values ('".$myData."')");`

how to format javascript date in that right for mysql  ?

Comment: do you really need the time part?

Comment: I am pretty sure this have been asked probably a few thousand of times before

Comment: the time is not important but it is added by datetime column type

Comment: use yy-mm-dd as it was worked in my case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you first verify that the datepicker is posting a correct value to the server?

Try alert the value somewhere.

If you have the correct input from the javascript, the php part of the script can be done like this:

```
if (isset$_GET['date']){$date=$_GET['date'];}
$date=date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime($date));
```

Echo out to confirm you have it right, and finally insert that $date into the table.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The date format in mysql is YYYY-MM-DD so you could use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):</strike>

```
$myDataSQL = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($myData));
mysqli_query($connect, "Insert into tab(date) values ('".$myDataSQL."')");
```

By the way, I would recommend using prepared statements to avoid sql injection problems although it does not really matter much in this specific case. I always use prepared statements so I don't have to think about it.

**Edit:** It seems [strtotime needs `/` separators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) for that to work.

If you are on PHP 5.3+ you can use the `DateTime` class:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-y', $myData);
$myDataSQL = $date->format('Y-m-d');
mysqli_query($connect, "Insert into tab(date) values ('".$myDataSQL."')");
```

Comment: @Snake Eyes It seems strtotime does not like your input format, see my edit.

Comment: that createFromFormat needs 2 args

Comment: yes but the fatal error occurs:  call to a member function format() on a non-object ...

Comment: @Snake Eyes Did you add your date as the second variable (I already edited my answer)?

Comment: yes, the problem is format not createfromformat. i have php 5.4.4

Comment: @Snake Eyes I have this working literally on php 5.3.10 and it also works on http://codepad.viper-7.com/DocphM. Must be something server specific in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

queryAccording to mysql [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> As a string in either 'YYYY-MM-DD' or 'YY-MM-DD' format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts. For example, '2012-12-31', '2012/12/31', '2012^12^31', and '2012@12@31' are equivalent.

so you could just change the format in which datepicker is taking the date.

```
$( ".item" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

putting that into your update should do the trick and you wont even need additional server operations for parsing. Just make sure it will reach the server safely.

Answer (score 0):

A different take on jeroen's answer which is just as suitable

```
$myDataSQL = date("c", strtotime($myData));
mysqli_query($connect, "Insert into tab(date) values ('".$myDataSQL."')");
```

I find using the ISO 8601 date everywhere easier to handle timezones as they are visible. Plus it inserts into mysql.

Also in the past I have had issues with jQuery datapicker in the needing to specify a better format in its initialisation.

Maybe try

```
$(".item").datepicker({
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: -30,
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a convertor (source code here: https://github.com/lingtalfi/DatePickerHelper/blob/master/DatePickerHelper.php)

Usage:

```
<?php
    echo DatePickerHelper::convertFromDatePickerToPhpDate("dd/mm/yy"); // prints d/m/Y
    echo DatePickerHelper::convertFromPhpDateToDatePicker("Y-m-d"); // prints yy-mm-dd
    $birthdayDate = "09/12/1944"; // your input from the web
    echo DatePickerHelper::convertFromNumericInputToMysqlDate($birthdayDate, "d/m/Y"); // 1944-12-09
```

-

```
class DatePickerHelper
{


    private static $map = [
        "yy" => "<1>",
        "y" => "<2>",
        "MM" => "<3>",
        "M" => "<4>",
        "mm" => "<5>",
        "m" => "<6>",
        "DD" => "<7>",
        "D" => "<8>",
        "oo" => "<9>",
        "o" => "<10>",
        "dd" => "<11>",
        "d" => "<12>",
    ];

    private static $map2 = [
        "<1>" => 'Y',
        "<2>" => 'y',
        "<3>" => 'F',
        "<4>" => 'M',
        "<5>" => 'm',
        "<6>" => 'n',
        "<7>" => 'l',
        "<8>" => 'D',
        "<9>" => 'z', // note: php doesn't have "day of the year with three digits", but this is the closest
        "<10>" => 'z',
        "<11>" => 'd',
        "<12>" => 'j',
    ];


    private static $mapRegex = [
        'Y' => '<1>',
        'y' => '<2>',
        'm' => '<3>',
        'n' => '<4>',
        'd' => '<5>',
        'j' => '<6>',
    ];

    private static $mapRegex2 = [
        '<1>' => '(?P<year4>[0-9]{4})',
        '<2>' => '(?P<year2>[0-9]{2})',
        '<3>' => '(?P<month_leading>[0-9]{2})',
        '<4>' => '(?P<month_no_leading>[0-9]{1,2})',
        '<5>' => '(?P<day_leading>[0-9]{2})',
        '<6>' => '(?P<day_no_leading>[0-9]{1,2})',
    ];


    public static function convertFromDatePickerToPhpDate(string $datePickerFormat): string
    {
        $map = self::$map;
        $map2 = self::$map2;
        $first = str_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $datePickerFormat);
        return str_replace(array_keys($map2), array_values($map2), $first);
    }

    public static function convertFromPhpDateToDatePicker(string $phpDate): string
    {
        $map2 = array_flip(self::$map2);
        $map = array_flip(self::$map);
        $first = str_replace(array_keys($map2), array_values($map2), $phpDate);
        return str_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $first);
    }


    /**
     * @param string $input , the string to convert, the format of this string should match the given phpFormat
     *                  Plus, it must contain exactly:
     *                          - one day component
     *                          - one month component
     *                          - one year component
     *
     * @param string $phpFormat , all components of the phpFormat  have to be one of those:
     *          - Y: year, four digits
     *          - y: year, two digits
     *          - m: numeric month, with leading zeros
     *          - n: numeric month, without leading zeros
     *          - d: numeric day of the month, with leading zeros
     *          - j: numeric day of the month, without leading zeros
     */
    public static function convertFromNumericInputToMysqlDate(string $input, string $phpFormat)
    {
        $map = self::$mapRegex;
        $map2 = self::$mapRegex2;
        $first = str_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $phpFormat);
        $pattern = str_replace(array_keys($map2), array_values($map2), $first);

        if (preg_match('!' . $pattern . '!', $input, $match)) {
            $day = $match['day_leading'] ?? $match['day_no_leading'] ?? null;
            if (null !== $day) {
                $day = (int)$day;
                $month = $match['month_leading'] ?? $match['month_no_leading'] ?? null;
                if (null !== $month) {
                    if (
                        array_key_exists("year4", $match) ||
                        array_key_exists("year2", $match)
                    ) {
                        // a component of each type is there, we will be able to return a result
                        if (array_key_exists("year4", $match)) {
                            $year = (int)$match['year4'];
                        } else {
                            // assumed it's 20, but we don't know really, that sucks.
                            // That's why you should use year4 instead...
                            $year = "20" . $match['year2'];
                            $year = (int)$year;
                        }

                        return $year . "-" . sprintf('%02s', $month) . "-" . sprintf("%02s", $day);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As in JavaScript date values are created using `let date = new Date("2017-01-26");`, you have to use the same format when formatting the date in your PHP script.

Just convert yout php date as following format `date('Y-m-d', $date)`.

This will give you the right format for javascript `<input type="date">` field.